# Por que fechar uma pergunta sobre API de transcrição de voz?

Tags: debate

Estive olhando essa pergunta feita ontem, onde o OP perguntou [Existe alguma Api de transcrição de áudio que possa ser usada em PHP, biblioteca em C ou em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27278/existe-alguma-api-de-transcri%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-%C3%A1udio-que-possa-ser-usada-em-php-biblioteca?noredirect=1#comment51134_27278)

Pelo meu ver é uma pergunta relacionada a programação, tem uma resposta certa e objetiva, não é baseada em opiniões e não é duplicata...

Então por tudo que já li aqui no meta e na SO-pt ainda não encontrei nenhum sentido em fechar essa pergunta...

Talvez a opinião de vocês seja diferente e se for o caso gostaria que me explicassem os motivos e o contexto em que essa pergunta deveria ser fechada

Comment: Já se encontra aberta.

Comment: @JorgeB. mesmo assim gostaria da opinião das pessoas que votaram para fechar a mesma... e obrigado

Comment: No meu caso eu não percebi a pergunta, só não votei porque não tinha a certeza se era erro meu ou do AP.

Comment: Talvez o pessoal que fechou (que pode ser visto [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/27278/revisions)) tenha pensado em um motivo que existe na matriz, onde se fecham perguntas que pedem por recomendação de bibliotecas. Acho que se permitimos isso por aqui já foi discutido antes, só que não lembro o que foi decidido e por isso me abstenho de votar por fechamento ou reabertura nesses casos.